# Badges Badges how do they work

Tags: discussion, etiquette, badges

To start with this is totally a personal greed/want based question. Please feel free to point out if people here find this offensive/ immature to even ask. I was looking up at gold badges that have been awarded to some dedicated members our SE group. I came to the "**Fanatic**" category ( **User has to visit the site for 100 consecutive days**) I saw something that made me question the basis on which the below users were awarded the fanatic badge.

[image]

How are the badges awarded to users who at least look very new based on their reputation.Are these  test user accounts from Stack exchange (or) are these 2 users genuinely visiting the site everyday and posting/ answering nothing at all ?

Comment: A fine question - the gamification is one of the StackExchange features that makes it fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect they might be accounts leveraging a script or similar to visit every day, or they could even just have the site set as a home page. I can't find the Jim Paris account right now so it looks as though the network's anti-abuse stuff might be in operation already, I guess we'll have to watch out to see what happens with the other one.

A few times I've made attempts at hitting 100 days but then a weekend away or something comes along and I totally forget to sign in.

Comment: Weekends are exactly where I fall of from my 100 days target :(.

Answer (score 2):

Both users are definitely scripts, take a look at their profiles. 101 and 88 accounts respectively all with fanatic and enthusiast badges.